# 3rd party app level temporary typings

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript-typings

Couple things on how to get custom typings to work in an [anuglar2 quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) project.

I am using the `outlayer` library https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer as an example.

I have configured `systemjs` to load the dependency. It is available and usable with `import * as outlayer from "outlayer";` however I still get the compile error `Cannot find module 'outlayer'.`

To fix this have added a typings file `outlayer.d.ts` directly to the `node_modules/outlayer` directory and updated the `package.json` to include `"typings": "./outlayer.d.ts",`.

```
//outlayer.d.ts

declare module Outlayer {

  function create(str:string):any;
}

export = Outlayer;
```

Adding this file directly to the node_module is less than ideal for obvious reasons. What is the better way to handle this without having to fork the library? Better yet, how can I get a simple/quick typings up probably at the app level so that I don't have to worry about writing out the entire thing right away? For example if I tried to use the `data` function right now I would see `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'typeof Outlayer'`

In summary just need to be able to write a custom app level typings that doesn't have all the goodies but also doesn't bark out all the errors. A sort of temporary typing to get by.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Create the file under somewhere (e.g. `custom-typings/outlayer.d.ts`)
2. Make it a script file (global typings):

   ```
   declare module 'outlayer' {
     function create(str: string): any;
   }
   ```
3. Install with `typings install file:custom-typings/outlayer.d.ts --global`

See if it helps.

EDIT: Updated step 3 above to add `--global`

Comment: works great, just need to install with the --global option.